# Get content of HttpWebResponse while debugging

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to run sequential requests to a web api url every 10 seconds to log changes in the data returned. The code snippet looks like this:

```
using (Stream objStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    query result = (query)serializer.Deserialize(objStream);
    Console.WriteLine(result.results.quote.Name + " " + result.results.quote.Ask);
    objStream.Flush();
    objStream.Close();
}
```

Every now and then an InvalidOperationException is thrown when running the deserialiation with the message saying that the XML document is badly formated. In an effort to isolate the problem I'm trying to find the "raw" response content in debug mode using the autos/locals/watch view, but I really can't find it.

I can find the response header and a lot of other information and as far as I can see this looks okay with one exception; the content-length which shows -1. I'm not sure if this is something that I should care about really but since I can't find the response "body" I can't help being suspicious about it.

So my real question here is: how can I find the "body" inside a `HttpWebResponse` or `Stream` object?

And the side question: Is the content-length with value -1 something to be bothered about.

Comment: Could you post your XML string ?

Comment: Hello, I run my poc against this YQL URL: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Name%2C%20Ask%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys This is the expected format and content of the response, but what the actual response looks like when the exception occurs is unknown, and that is what I would like to be able to find out in debug mode.

Comment: The response stream is for output, why are you using it for input?

Comment: @Jonny, I'm not? The request is done using `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: That code is ok. There is something wrong with your class structure 'query'.

Comment: Anyway, if you read the entire contents from the stream and store it in a variable Before deserializing it, you should be able to see the contents while debuggin

Comment: @x: Okey. I will have a look. I used the "Paste special" in VS 2013 to generate the classes, and I guess the example query used could be too "simple" to cover all scenarios.

Comment: Yes, if you look at that yahoo xml, the class structure will be very complex.

Comment: @Jonny: I should have thought about that. I guess I was too focused on finding it in the debug views.

Comment: This is not using XmlSerializer, but do the same thing : http://www.jarloo.com/get-yahoo-finance-api-data-via-yql/

Comment: @x Yeah I've seen that page, but thought that using xml serializer was much more neat (If working). Thanks to @Jonny I was able to capture the response causing the exception and it's weird. It only contains the last two comments of the expected document: <!-- total: 1317 -->
<!-- prod_bf1_1;paas.yql;queryyahooapiscomproductionbf1;44119674-4f9a-11e6-874c-d4ae52974741 --> I guess this is another question though.

Comment: @Jonny, Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the entire contents from the stream and store it in a variable before deserializing it, you should be able to see the contents while debugging

Answer (score 0):

For debugging i would suggest you replicate the response into string and that way you watch it.

```
using (Stream objStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objStream);

  string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
  objStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin); // Get the pointer back to the begining.                

    query result = (query)serializer.Deserialize(objStream);
    Console.WriteLine(result.results.quote.Name + " " + result.results.quote.Ask);
    objStream.Flush(); // remove
    objStream.Close();//remove
}
```

I would also recommend to remove:
objStream.Flush();
objStream.Close();

when using 'using' statement it calls Dispose() (IDisposable()), which will eventauly close the stream by itself .